# How I make this jquery slide show?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am trying to make a slide show as my home page banner. Here I use jquery `localscroll.js` and `scrollTo.js` plugins.

This is my Javascript -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slideshow").css("overflow", "hidden");
    $("#slideshow-nav").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#slideshow-nav a[href=#oron5]").addClass("active");

    $("#slideshow-nav").localScroll({
        target:'#slideshow', axis: 'x'
    });

    $("#slideshow-nav a").click(function(){
        $("#slideshow-nav a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }); 
});
```

Here I need to click navigation button to view images. So Can I know, how do I make this to change images automatically after some times?

This is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TZk86/4/) so far.

Can anybody help me to figure this out.
Thank you.

Comment: This is another FIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/TZk86/5/ and also this is not working in google chrome

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to set an interval and use jQuery's .click() function. For example, try adding this code to the end of your $(document).ready() function:

```
var count = 2;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if(count > 5) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    $("#slideshow-nav li:nth-child(" + count + ") a").click();
    ++count;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Its working only once as soon as page is loaded. Can we get it work as a loop?

Comment: @TNK Notice that I told it to stop when count > 5. If you want it to loop, change that code. You'll know what to do.